# How to update created elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple function that will create a paragraph.

```js
function appendElements() {
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  const createDiv = document.createElement("div");
  createDiv.classList.add("myDiv");
  const createP = document.createElement("P");
  createP.classList.add("myParagraph");
  createP.innerHTML = input.value;
  createDiv.appendChild(createP);
  const div = document.getElementById("examplediv");
  div.appendChild(createDiv);
}
```

And another function that will sum the `innerHTML` of the divs, and create a div element for the result.

```js
function calculateSum() {
  let div = document.getElementsByClassName("myParagraph");
  let array = new Array;
  for (var i = 0; i <div.length; i++) {
    array.push(div[i].innerHTML);
  }

  let numberedArray = array.map((i) => Number(i));

  const sumArray = numberedArray.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
      }, 0);
  
  const createElement = document.createElement("div");
  createElement.innerHTML = sumArray;
  document.getElementById("divForAvg").appendChild(createElement);
}
```

And the last function that will change the `innerHTML` of the paragraph element when clicked.

```js
function editELement() {
  const input2 = document.getElementById("myInput2")
    let items = document.getElementsByClassName("myParagraph");
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
            items[i].onclick = function(){
            items[i].innerHTML = input2.value;
          }
        }
}
```

So basically when I create some paragraphs and execute the second function, the second function will calculate the sum of the paragraphs and create a div with the sum inside.

What I want is when I remove one of the paragraph elements or edit them, I want the previously created divs to update(recalculate the sum), I have literally no idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try this using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). I have interpreted what I think you are looking for (note: it's exemplary, but it may give you an idea for your code) and reduced your code a bit for the example. Note the 2 different ways to create new elements (`insertAdjacentHTML` and `Object.assign`).

You can play with the code [@Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67104192-example?file=index.js).

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "create") {
    return appendInputValueElement();
  }
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("remove")) {
    return removeThis(evt.target);
  }
  if (evt.target.id === "clear") {
    document.querySelector("#accumulated ul").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
  }
}

function appendInputValueElement() {
  const input = document.querySelector(".myInput");
  const div = document.querySelector("#exampleDiv");
  exampleDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", `
    <div class="myDiv">
      <button class="remove">remove</button>
      <span class="myParagraph">${input.value || 0}</span>
    </div>  
  `);
  calculateSum();
}

function removeThis(elem) {
  elem.closest(".myDiv").remove();
  calculateSum();
}

function calculateSum() {
  const allParas = [...document.querySelectorAll(".myParagraph")];
  const sum = allParas.reduce( (acc, val) => acc + +val.textContent, 0);
  document.querySelector("#accumulated ul")
    .append(Object.assign(document.createElement("li"), {textContent: sum}));
  document.querySelector(".currentSum").dataset.currentSum = sum;
  
  if (sum < 1) {
    document.querySelector("#accumulated ul").innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
.currentSum::after {
  content: ' 'attr(data-current-sum);
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.myParagraph {
  color: red;
}

.accSums, .currentSum, .myDiv {
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
 A number please: <input class="myInput" type="number" value="12">
 <button id="create">create value</button>
</div>
<div class="currentSum" data-current-sum="0">*Current sum</div>
<p id="exampleDiv"></p>
<div id="accumulated">
  <div class="accSums">*Accumulated sums</div>
  <ul></ul>
  <button id="clear">Clear accumulated</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering, i still have a doubt here, this code creates a new div when i delete an element but i want to update(change) the already created elements

Comment: i'll try to explain. so when i create my first value the calculatesum function will calculate the sum of 1st value, when i create another value it will calculate the sum of 1st and 2nd value, when i create another it will calculate sum of 1st, 2nd and 3rd and it goes on.and when i remove the a value, lets say the 1st value, the 2nd value has now become the 1st value and 3rd value has become 2nd value, so the already created div that has the sum of of 1st and 2nd value previously will now have to recalculate the sum of the new 1st and 2nd value and change div to the new sum, is this possible?xD

Comment: "_this code creates a new div when i delete an element_" that's **not** what it does.
I have adjusted the code [@Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67104192-example?file=index.js), maybe that makes things more clear?

Comment: eh now that code does not create new elements for the sum (?)

Comment: I was still busy. Now it should work as expected

Comment: hmm it still doesnt (?) maybe can you try share the link again? :D

Comment: Try Ctrl/Shift+F5 or click the previous link again ;)

Comment: no i mean it still doesnt create new elements for the sum

Comment: But please, tell me *exactly* what you mean. The example code @stackblitz creates a div for every value (with a possibility to dis-/enable it) and for all actions (re)calculates the sum of the active values (displayed after *Current sum). Furthermore, the code is probably not exactly what you need, it's meant to give you a clue or some to write your own code.

Answer (score 1):

i've changed `calculateSum` you can call it when you edited paragraph. If `summParagraph` doesn't exists then we create it.

```
function calculateSum() {
  let div = document.getElementsByClassName("myParagraph");
  let array = new Array;
  for (var i = 0; i <div.length; i++) {
    array.push(div[i].innerHTML);
  }

  let numberedArray = array.map((i) => Number(i));

  const sumArray = numberedArray.reduce(function(a, b){
        return a + b;
      }, 0);
  
  if (!document.getElementById("summParagraph")) {
    const createElement = document.createElement("div");
    createElement.setAttribute("id", "summParagraph");
    document.getElementById("divForAvg").appendChild(createElement);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("summParagraph").innerHTML = summArray;
}
```

Comment: hi thx for answering, i have a doubt here, so if an element is already created it will not create any elements anymore? i want it to not only update it but also keep on creating elements can you help me on this?

Comment: The you just call the previous `calculateSum` after you edited or remove something